# asp.net core app. 500 - Internal server error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, hosting

I uploaded my website to godaddy windows hosting with plesk.
All files are uploaded but I get an error:

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

From researching the problem online I figured the prob;em must be in my web.config file

I am showing here what I have in my web.config:

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false" allowOverride="false">
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
  <handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
  <trust level="Full" />
 </system.web>
 </location>
 <system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: and why do you think the problem is in the web.config?

Comment: If I rename the web.config file to something else I don't get the error (the website doesn't load obviously, it just shows a list of files and folders in my httodocs folder).      So I figured that the web.config doesn't load correctly.        Correct me if I'm wrong or any other suggestions

Comment: Well, if you rename that file then your application doesn't run at all. So it doesn't prove the problem has to do with web.config.

Comment: This is an http general error meaning something went wrong at server side. However any unhandled exception can potentially return Internal Server Error to the client. To make progress you need to know what the actual error is. If you can't debug remotely then my suggestion is to enable error logging at server.

Comment: I have this: `stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout` in my web.config which I thought would write the errors but it doesn't write anything to the file. In my websites error log this is the error: 500 19 13 1380 237 5140

Comment: have you tried this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxyDwX75vm4

Comment: I did! Nothing seems to work..... I'll try contacting plesk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [web.config in asp.net MVC core Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174082/web-config-in-asp-net-mvc-core-project)

Comment: How is your issue? 500 internal server error is generic issue. You need to check full error message on the server and then please paste it here.

Comment: I wasn't able to see any other info anywhere. I had since answered this question (I changed hosting) and it's working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after trying everything including calling godaddy and searching all over, I found out that GoDaddy doesn't support asp.net core 2.0 applications

I hosted with 1and1 windows hosting and it runs!

Comment: Yes, if they don't support it, your .net core 2.0 won't work. I use asphostportal here and they also support newest .net core 2

Answer (score 3):

Your host (GoDaddy) will need to setup their servers to support asp.net core

[web.config in asp.net MVC core Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174082/web-config-in-asp-net-mvc-core-project)

I tried on myproject also, but it didn't work

Comment: But after asking GoDaddy to set up their servers it did work?